# MongoDB: Split multi-serie in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, matplotlib

I have loaded a set of tweet in a MongoDB DB, and calculated the number of tweets grouped per month per User.

I have a list as below:

| _id | User | Month | NbTweet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | User1 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | User2 | 1 | 15 |
| 4 | User2 | 2 | 25 |
| 5 | User3 | 1 | 12 |
| 6 | User3 | 2 | 22 |

but I would like to get the data in that form to draw a multi line chart with Matplotlib:

| _month | User1 | User2 | User3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | 12 |
| 2 | 20 | 25 | 22 |

Should the transformation happen in MongoDB as a pipeline, or is there any way with Pandas to transform the data ?

THANKS,

MadSurfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 'User': ['User1', 'User1', 'User2', 'User2', 'User3', 'User3'],
 'Month': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 'NbTweet': [10, 20, 15, 25, 12, 22]})

>>> df1
   id   User  Month  NbTweet
0   1  User1      1       10
1   2  User1      2       20
2   3  User2      1       15
3   4  User2      2       25
4   5  User3      1       12
5   6  User3      2       22

>>> df.set_index(['Month','User']).unstack()['NbTweet']
 User   User1  User2  User3
Month
1         10     15     12
2         20     25     22
```